# Swift parse JSON to Model Object

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I had this method here and it returned my data exactly as I needed it:

```
func getTestData() -> [Any]?
    {
        return [GradingData(lot: "lot", andColumns: "andColumns", SLAIssuedFinalGrading: true, SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate: "SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate", CityApprovalIssued: true, CityCommentReceived: false, GradingRepair: "GradingRepair", CurbStopRepair: "CurbStopRepair", SplashPadDownSpout: "SplashPadDownSpout", RYCBOtherRepairs: "RYCBOtherRepairs", Comments: "Comments", columnCamera: "", DepositReceived: false), GradingData(lot: "lot", andColumns: "andColumns2", SLAIssuedFinalGrading: false, SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate: "SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate", CityApprovalIssued: false, CityCommentReceived: false, GradingRepair: "GradingRepair", CurbStopRepair: "CurbStopRepair", SplashPadDownSpout: "SplashPadDownSpout", RYCBOtherRepairs: "RYCBOtherRepairs", Comments: "Comments", columnCamera: "", DepositReceived: false)]
    }
```

Now I am trying to do a call to an API and return the exact same structure with this:

```
func GetLandGradingData(_ community: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: [GradingData]) -> Void)
    {

        let escapedCommunity = community.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

        let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: webservice + "?community=" + escapedCommunity!);
        urlComponents?.user = appDelegate.username;
        urlComponents?.password = appDelegate.password;

        let url = urlComponents?.url;

        let returnedData = [GradingData]()

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            if(error != nil){

                completion(returnedData)

            }else{

                do{

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [GradingData]

                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({

                        completion(json)

                    })

                }catch let error as NSError{

                    print(error)
                    completion(returnedData)

                }
            }

        }).resume()

    }
```

My problem is that is method is not returning the same structure as the getTestData method, attached are screenshots on what getTestData returns and what this api method call returns.

[image]
[image]

Here is my whole class:

```
@objcMembers class GradingData : NSObject {

    /**
     Define lot Column String
     */
    var lot: String?
    /**
     Define Address Column String
     */
    var address: String?
    /**
     Define SLA Issued Final Grading Column String
     */
    var SLAIssuedFinalGrading = false
    /**
     Define SLA Issued Final Grading Date Column String
     */
    var SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate: String?
    /**
     Define City Approval Issued Column String
     */
    var CityApprovalIssued = false
    /**
     Define City Comment Received Column String
     */
    var CityCommentReceived = false
    /**
     Define Grading Repair Column String
     */
    var GradingRepair: String?
    /**
     Define Curb Stop Repair Column String
     */
    var CurbStopRepair: String?
    /**
     Define Splash Pad or Down Spout Column String
     */
    var SplashPadDownSpout: String?
    /**
     Define RYCB or Other Repairs Column String
     */
    var RYCBOtherRepairs: String?
    /**
     Define Comments Column String
     */
    var Comments: String?
    /**
     Define Camera Column String
     */
    var columnCamera: String?
    /**
     Define Deposit Received Column String
     */
    var DepositReceived = false


    /**
     Inital call to class
     */
    init(lot: String?, andColumns address: String?, SLAIssuedFinalGrading: Bool?, SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate: String?, CityApprovalIssued: Bool?, CityCommentReceived: Bool?, GradingRepair: String?, CurbStopRepair: String?, SplashPadDownSpout: String?, RYCBOtherRepairs: String?, Comments: String?, columnCamera: String?, DepositReceived: Bool?) {

        super.init()

        //Set lot string

        self.lot = lot

        //Set Address Column string

        self.address = address

        //Set SLA Issued Final Grading Column string

        self.SLAIssuedFinalGrading = SLAIssuedFinalGrading!

        //Set SLA Issued Final Grading Date Column string

        self.SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate = SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate

        //Set City Approval Issued Column string

        self.CityApprovalIssued = CityApprovalIssued!

        //Set City Comment Received Column string

        self.CityCommentReceived = CityCommentReceived!

        //Set Grading Repair Column string

        self.GradingRepair = GradingRepair

        //Set Curb Stop Repair Column string

        self.CurbStopRepair = CurbStopRepair

        //Set Splash Pad or Down Spout Column string

        self.SplashPadDownSpout = SplashPadDownSpout

        //Set RYCB or Other Repairs Column string

        self.RYCBOtherRepairs = RYCBOtherRepairs

        //Set Comments Column string

        self.Comments = Comments

        //Set Camera Column string

        self.columnCamera = columnCamera

        //Set Deposit Received Column string

        self.DepositReceived = DepositReceived!

    }
}
```

Here is my Data from the API:

```
<Reports>
<CityApprovalIssued>false</CityApprovalIssued>
<CityCommentReceived>false</CityCommentReceived>
<Comments></Comments>
<CurbStopRepair></CurbStopRepair>
<DepositReceived>false</DepositReceived>
<GradingRepair></GradingRepair>
<RYCBOtherRepairs></RYCBOtherRepairs>
<SLAIssuedFinalGrading>false</SLAIssuedFinalGrading>
<SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate/>
<SplashPadDownSpout></SplashPadDownSpout>
<address>123 Fake Street</address>
<lot>A0001</lot>
</Reports>
<Reports>
<CityApprovalIssued>false</CityApprovalIssued>
<CityCommentReceived>false</CityCommentReceived>
<Comments></Comments>
<CurbStopRepair></CurbStopRepair>
<DepositReceived>false</DepositReceived>
<GradingRepair></GradingRepair>
<RYCBOtherRepairs></RYCBOtherRepairs>
<SLAIssuedFinalGrading>false</SLAIssuedFinalGrading>
<SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate/>
<SplashPadDownSpout></SplashPadDownSpout>
<address>125 Fake Street</address>
<lot>A0002</lot>
</Reports>
```

This is from an ASP.NET MVC API Controller: `<ArrayOfReports xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/App.Models">`

This is what I get when I do this:

```
let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)

print(string as Any)

Optional("[{\"lot\":\"A0001\",\"address\”:\”123 Fake Street\”,\”SLAIssuedFinalGrading\":false,\"SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate\":\"\",\"CityApprovalIssued\":false,\"CityCommentReceived\":false,\"GradingRepair\":\"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \",\"CurbStopRepair\":\"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \",\"SplashPadDownSpout\":\"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \",\"RYCBOtherRepairs\":\"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \",\"Comments\":\"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \",\"DepositReceived\":false},{\"lot\":\"A0002\",\"address\":\"125 Fake Street\",\"SLAIssuedFinalGrading\":false,\"SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate\":\"\",\"CityApprovalIssued\":false,\"CityCommentReceived\":false,\"GradingRepair\":\"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \",\"CurbStopRepair\":\"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \",\"SplashPadDownSpout\":\"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \",\"RYCBOtherRepairs\":\"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \",\"Comments\":\"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \",\"DepositReceived\":false}]")
```

Comment: Where do you parse the json and create the model?

Comment: The model is a class that is in another file.

Comment: You **cannot** deserialize JSON directly into a model with `JSONSerialization` (unless `GradingData` is a type alias for a JSON dictionary or array). You could do it with `JSONDecoder` and the `Decodable` protocol

Comment: Example please?

Comment: [Here are many examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BSwift%5D+decodable)

Comment: The question cannot be answered without knowing the JSON. Please add the JSON string (**not** the deserialized value of `json`). And do you really need a class as model?

Comment: http://leaks.wanari.com/2016/08/24/xml-parsing-swift/

Comment: Can you put an example and an answer?

Comment: This is **XML**, not JSON.

Comment: Then how come I am able to use this? `let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! Array<GradingData>' data is gettting populated to json

Comment: If the source is XML, the line throws an error. And if the source is JSON the line crashes because a JSON object cannot be converted to a class. Please create a string from the received data `let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)` and print this. Or do you use a third-party library for parsing?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 6):

First of all the response data is indeed JSON, the XML output is a bit confusing.

You probably don't need a class inherited from `NSObject`, in most cases especially in iOS a struct is sufficient.

Except the key `columnCamera` all keys exist in all records, so declare all properties as non-optional without a default value and `columnCamera` as optional, and declare all properties as constants (`let`) if they are not going to change.

An explicit `init` method is not needed.

The `CodingKeys` are added to translate most of the keys to lowercase.

```
struct GradingData : Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case lot, address, SLAIssuedFinalGrading
        case SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate
        case cityApprovalIssued = "CityApprovalIssued"
        case cityCommentReceived = "CityCommentReceived"
        case gradingRepair = "GradingRepair"
        case curbStopRepair = "CurbStopRepair"
        case splashPadDownSpout = "SplashPadDownSpout"
        case RYCBOtherRepairs, comments = "Comments"
        case columnCamera, depositReceived = "DepositReceived"
    }

    let lot: String
    let address: String
    let SLAIssuedFinalGrading : Bool
    let SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate: String
    let cityApprovalIssued : Bool
    let cityCommentReceived : Bool
    let gradingRepair : String
    let curbStopRepair : String
    let splashPadDownSpout : String
    let RYCBOtherRepairs : String
    let comments : String
    let columnCamera : String?
    let depositReceived : Bool

}
```

Then decode the JSON

```
....

var returnedData = [GradingData]()
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
     if error != nil {
         print(error!)
         completion(returnedData)
     } else {
         do {
            returnedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([GradingData].self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(returnedData)
            }
         } catch {
             print(error)
             completion(returnedData)
         }
     }
 }).resume()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because you asked for an example (but did not provide your `GradingData` which will make this really abstract):

```
struct GradingData : Codable {
    // here is the meat, but you did not show ...
}

...

let grades = JSONDecoder().decode(GradingData.self, from: data)
```

Swift is the first language I have come across which has nailed this. It *really* just boils down to implementing an interface (without actually doing anything interesting most of the time while still providing the possibility to do all the necessary things with minimal effort) and get a *free* JSON parser for your objects (not just some hash-junk dictionary).

(It is called "progress" :-)

Comment: I get this error with your code: In argument type 'GradingData.Type', 'GradingData' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'

Comment: I added my whole class

Comment: The error you are getting tells you exactly what you need to do. Right now `GradingData` does not conform to `Decodable`, you need to make it so that `GradingData` _does_ conform to `Decodable` (or `Codable` if you think you will need to send data as well as receive it). If you Google "Swift Decodable" you will get plenty of info on what you need to do. The short version is change `@objcMembers class GradingData : NSObject` to `@objcMembers class GradingData : NSObject, Codable` or `@objcMembers class GradingData : NSObject, Decodable`

Comment: Your code will be greatly simplified if you use the version of @vadian. `structs` already generate an appropriate initializer and if you do not _have_ to modify grades after you created them you should avoid `var` and do yourself a favour and omit optionals wherever  you can. This will greatly reduce the potential for errors (which Swift is very good at pointing out though) and improve the possible optimisations. Try it out, it can be that simple (and that is the point of Swift and `Codable` in particular).

Answer (score 2):

Just add another `init` into your `GradingData` model class like this:

```
convenience init(data: [String : Any]) {
 init(lot: data["lot"] as? String,
 andColumns: data["address"] as? String,
 SLAIssuedFinalGrading: data["SLAIssuedFinalGrading"] as? Bool,
 SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate: data["SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate"] as? String, 
 CityApprovalIssued: data["CityApprovalIssued"] as? Bool,
 CityCommentReceived: data["CityCommentReceived"] as? Bool,
 GradingRepair: data["GradingRepair"] as? String,
 CurbStopRepair: data["CurbStopRepair"] as? String,
 SplashPadDownSpout: data["SplashPadDownSpout"] as? String,
 RYCBOtherRepairs: data["RYCBOtherRepairs"] as? String,
 Comments: data["Comments"] as? String,
 columnCamera: data["columnCamera"] as? String,
 DepositReceived: data["DepositReceived"] as? Bool)
}
```

And in `func GetLandGradingData(...)` method replace inside `do { }` braces with these:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [[String : Any]]

                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                       let gradingDatas = json.map { GradingData(data: $0) }

                        completion(gradingDatas)

                    })
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert XML to dictionary by custom class or nsxmlparser.
or if u have array of Grading then

```
var modelArr = [Grading]()
```

`var model = Grading.init(fromDictionary dictionary: xmlParsedDic)`
`modelArr.append(model)`

use this model class

```
import Foundation
```

`class Grading : NSObject, NSCoding {`

```
var cityApprovalIssued : Bool!
var cityCommentReceived : Bool!
var comments : String!
var curbStopRepair : String!
var depositReceived : Bool!
var gradingRepair : String!
var rYCBOtherRepairs : String!
var sLAIssuedFinalGrading : Bool!
var sLAIssuedFinalGradingDate : String!
var splashPadDownSpout : String!
var address : String!
var lot : String!


init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){
    cityApprovalIssued = dictionary["CityApprovalIssued"] as? Bool
    cityCommentReceived = dictionary["CityCommentReceived"] as? Bool
    comments = dictionary["Comments"] as? String
    curbStopRepair = dictionary["CurbStopRepair"] as? String
    depositReceived = dictionary["DepositReceived"] as? Bool
    gradingRepair = dictionary["GradingRepair"] as? String
    rYCBOtherRepairs = dictionary["RYCBOtherRepairs"] as? String
    sLAIssuedFinalGrading = dictionary["SLAIssuedFinalGrading"] as? Bool
    sLAIssuedFinalGradingDate = dictionary["SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate"] as? String
    splashPadDownSpout = dictionary["SplashPadDownSpout"] as? String
    address = dictionary["address"] as? String
    lot = dictionary["lot"] as? String
}

func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
{
    var dictionary = [String:Any]()
    if cityApprovalIssued != nil{
        dictionary["CityApprovalIssued"] = cityApprovalIssued
    }
    if cityCommentReceived != nil{
        dictionary["CityCommentReceived"] = cityCommentReceived
    }
    if comments != nil{
        dictionary["Comments"] = comments
    }
    if curbStopRepair != nil{
        dictionary["CurbStopRepair"] = curbStopRepair
    }
    if depositReceived != nil{
        dictionary["DepositReceived"] = depositReceived
    }
    if gradingRepair != nil{
        dictionary["GradingRepair"] = gradingRepair
    }
    if rYCBOtherRepairs != nil{
        dictionary["RYCBOtherRepairs"] = rYCBOtherRepairs
    }
    if sLAIssuedFinalGrading != nil{
        dictionary["SLAIssuedFinalGrading"] = sLAIssuedFinalGrading
    }
    if sLAIssuedFinalGradingDate != nil{
        dictionary["SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate"] = sLAIssuedFinalGradingDate
    }
    if splashPadDownSpout != nil{
        dictionary["SplashPadDownSpout"] = splashPadDownSpout
    }
    if address != nil{
        dictionary["address"] = address
    }
    if lot != nil{
        dictionary["lot"] = lot
    }
    return dictionary
}

@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
     cityApprovalIssued = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "CityApprovalIssued") as? Bool
     cityCommentReceived = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "CityCommentReceived") as? Bool
     comments = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Comments") as? String
     curbStopRepair = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "CurbStopRepair") as? String
     depositReceived = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "DepositReceived") as? Bool
     gradingRepair = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "GradingRepair") as? String
     rYCBOtherRepairs = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "RYCBOtherRepairs") as? String
     sLAIssuedFinalGrading = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "SLAIssuedFinalGrading") as? Bool
     sLAIssuedFinalGradingDate = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate") as? String
     splashPadDownSpout = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "SplashPadDownSpout") as? String
     address = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "address") as? String
     lot = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "lot") as? String

}

@objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    if cityApprovalIssued != nil{
        aCoder.encode(cityApprovalIssued, forKey: "CityApprovalIssued")
    }
    if cityCommentReceived != nil{
        aCoder.encode(cityCommentReceived, forKey: "CityCommentReceived")
    }
    if comments != nil{
        aCoder.encode(comments, forKey: "Comments")
    }
    if curbStopRepair != nil{
        aCoder.encode(curbStopRepair, forKey: "CurbStopRepair")
    }
    if depositReceived != nil{
        aCoder.encode(depositReceived, forKey: "DepositReceived")
    }
    if gradingRepair != nil{
        aCoder.encode(gradingRepair, forKey: "GradingRepair")
    }
    if rYCBOtherRepairs != nil{
        aCoder.encode(rYCBOtherRepairs, forKey: "RYCBOtherRepairs")
    }
    if sLAIssuedFinalGrading != nil{
        aCoder.encode(sLAIssuedFinalGrading, forKey: "SLAIssuedFinalGrading")
    }
    if sLAIssuedFinalGradingDate != nil{
        aCoder.encode(sLAIssuedFinalGradingDate, forKey: "SLAIssuedFinalGradingDate")
    }
    if splashPadDownSpout != nil{
        aCoder.encode(splashPadDownSpout, forKey: "SplashPadDownSpout")
    }
    if address != nil{
        aCoder.encode(address, forKey: "address")
    }
    if lot != nil{
        aCoder.encode(lot, forKey: "lot")
    }

}}
```